# Get the PID of a process started with sudo via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sudo

I need the process id of a process (here `sleep 20`) started remotely via SSH and `sudo`.

`date` is inserted to illustrate the duration of the SSH connection. Without connection there is also no process on my remote machine, of course.

```
$ date; ssh pc1 "sleep 20 & echo \$!"; date                            # works
Mi 20. Jan 16:18:29 CET 2016
11540
Mi 20. Jan 16:18:50 CET 2016
$ date; ssh pc1 "echo password | sudo -S sleep 20"; date               # works
Mi 20. Jan 16:20:44 CET 2016
[sudo] password for lab: Mi 20. Jan 16:21:04 CET 2016
$ date; ssh pc1 "echo password | sudo -S sleep 20 & echo \$!"; date    # does not
Mi 20. Jan 16:21:55 CET 2016
11916
Mi 20. Jan 16:21:56 CET 2016
```

On a second machine the last, complete command works fine:

```
$ date; ssh pc2 "echo password | sudo -S sleep 20 & echo \$!"; date
Mi 20. Jan 16:23:40 CET 2016
6035
[sudo] password for lab: Mi 20. Jan 16:24:01 CET 2016
```

Any suggestion why there is this different behaviour of the two machines?

*Info: I know the risk of clear passwords but it's a shared account in an isolated test network.*

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more appropriate for the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Comment: It means that my process is not running on remote machine. Either it's killed due closed connection or vice versa.

Comment: Alas, this question is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://ServerFault.com (professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration). Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your question and ask the moderator to move it to the correct site. (Please don't post the same question on multiple sites.)

Comment: I flagged it to move. For me it is Shell/Bash programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an issue with incomplete process dependencies. With some additional milliseconds the connection (and process) keeps established the whole time.

```
$ date; ssh pc1 "echo password | sudo -S sleep 20 & echo \$! && sleep 0.01"; date
Do 21. Jan 14:50:39 CET 2016
[sudo] password for lab: 6841
Do 21. Jan 14:51:00 CET 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$ remote_pid=$(ssh mauro@planck 'sleep 20 > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!')
$ echo $remote_pid
13878
```

or...

```
$ remote_pid=$(ssh mauro@planck 'echo secret | sudo -S sleep 20 > /tmp/log 2>&1  & echo $!')
```

Comment: Where is the input of user's password to execute sudo?

Comment: Except for the output pipe to a file it's exactly the same as mine and does not work, too. In the logfile there is only the prompt for password of sudo (from stderr).

Comment: The `$!`must be escaped that it's interpreted from remote shell instead of local one.